Functions that are continuous everywhere and discontinuous everywhere
Are there any functions $f:\mathbb{R\rightarrow R}$ such that for any $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, $a<b \implies$ there are infinitely many $\alpha,\beta\in(a,b)$ such that $f$ is continuous at $\alpha$ and $f$ is discontinuous at $\beta$ ?
That sounds very counterintuitive, but there are functions that are discontinuous at almost every point like
$$ \begin{equation}
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
x \text{ if } x\in\mathbb Q \\
0 \text{ if } x\notin\mathbb Q
\end{cases}
\end{equation}$$
And I am unable to show a function can’t have continuities and discontinuities that intensely near each other, nor can I give an example of it.
My work:
Take $\alpha_1$ to be a continuity. $\forall \epsilon_1 >0, \exists \delta_1>0,$ such that $|x-\alpha_1|<\delta_1\implies|f(x)-f(\alpha_1)|<\epsilon_1 $
Take $\beta_1$ to be a discontinuity. $\exists \epsilon_2 >0, \forall\delta_2>0, \exists x, |x-\beta_1|<\delta_2$ such that $|f(x)-f(\beta_1)|\ge\epsilon_2 $
I know that is literally just the definition of limit, but I can’t see anywhere to start with. I can restrict $\beta_1$ such that $|\beta_1-\alpha_1|<\delta_1$, same with $\alpha_1$, and maybe continue the process infinitely.
Does anyone know how to prove or disprove the existence of such a function? Any hints are appreciated!

Thomae's function is a classic example.
